# WP7 Converter in ResourceDictionary

Tags: windows-phone-7, resourcedictionary

On the page we declare a converter as

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
   <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

How to declare it in ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to declare it in ResourceDictionary?

```
<local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Comment: Not sure how this is correct, because your not declaring it in a resourcedictionary

Comment: @MyKuLLSK - The question was about declaring it in a resource dictionary, not about declaring the resource dictionary itself.

Comment: @ZombieSheep - That doesn't make seance. He already answered his own question then

Comment: I assumed he had enough brain to write `<ResourceDictionary>` himself :-)

Comment: This answer is correct! I needed to declare it inside resourcedictionary. I also tried as Claus answered, but was receiving an error. I blamed declaring of Converter, but in real the error was because of wrong using of TemplateBinding with Converter.

Answer (score 1):

#### Add this in App.xaml

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
               <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Actually this implies that it's in the application resources. Could also be in a external file. (And you forgot the namespace)

Comment: Um NO. I didn't!! WPF has a built in BoolToVisibilityConverter...If your going to talk trash about my answer you better be correct

Comment: And look at the BOLD it says add this to App.xaml