# WP programmatically reference TextBlock in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, reference, windows-phone-8

I am trying to is disable the visibility of the TextBlock. I can reference the TextBlock in the following example:

**XAML File**

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Pivot 1">
   <TextBlock Text="hello world" x:Name="dummytext" />
</phone:PivotItem>
```

**CS File**

```
dummytext.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

But I can't reference it when I have this following code:

**XAML File**

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Dummy.Title}">
  <Grid Margin="0,0,-12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="Box1">
      <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Dummy.Items}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>

              <Grid>
                //REFERENCE THIS TEXTBLOCK
                <TextBlock Text="hello world" x:Name="dummytext" />
              </Grid>

              <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="byee world" x:Name="dummytext2" />
                <TextBlock Text="bye2 world" x:Name="dummytext3" />
              </Grid>

            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
      </phone:LongListSelector>
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

I am new to Windows Phone development and still learning. Can you point me to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Actully you are binded textblock in LongListSelector so you can not directly use it ...

Comment: I think (since you are using longlist selector) you should point to the index of the Longlistselection item you want to hide. Something like LonglistSelector.ItemIdex (something like that). But one thing is certain, you can't access it right now, because its a child of Longlist Selector. You can't access it directly

Comment: first you have to find it than you can use it of textblock property

Comment: I did not know that. I will try your solution Bart.

Comment: This should help: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to set the visibility of a control, a suitable approach would be for you to use a visibility “converter”, send a property in your entity to the converter and then return the desired Visibility state.

```
 public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visible;

        bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out visible);

        return visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Define your converter

You can place this in the app.xaml file so that you whole app has access to it when required.

```
<Application  xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfYourConverter;assembly=AssemplyOfYourConverter">
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Set your xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="hello world" x:Name="dummytext" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
```

see [Converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078789/wp7-converter-in-resourcedictionary) or Bing "value converters wp8" for more on creating converters

Comment: Its giving me the following error. `The resource "VisibilityConverter" could not be resolved.` I'm sure this is a silly error on my part.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working now. But something strange is happening. Its giving me an error `Invalid XAML.` But it runs with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

FInd your textblock from LongListSelector through visual tree than use propert of textblock

refere below link

[How to find a specific element inside a control using Visual tree in WP7](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_find_a_specific_element_inside_a_control_using_Visual_tree_in_WP7)

[Visual Tree Enumeration](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx)

[Find image control using visual tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886640/run-throguh-visual-tree-and-set-all-images-to-null)